# Rでデータフレームの日本語を0, 1に置き換える関数を自作した時のトラブル

Tags: r

よろしくお願いします。

Rで
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

のようなデータフレームの「あり」、「なし」を1, 0 に変更しようと思って以下のような自作の関数を書きましたが、もとのデータフレームに変更が反映されておらず、要素は「あり」、「なし」のままでした。

```
nihongosayonara <- function(df) {
  for(i in 1:length(names(df))){
    df[i][df[i] == "あり"] <- 1
    df[i][df[i] == "なし"] <- 0}}
```

この際特にエラーやWarningは出ませんでした。
関数内部の終わりにprint()で列を見てみると変更されているようです。

手作業で

```
df[1][df[1] == "あり"] <- 1
df[1][df[1] == "なし"] <- 0
```

のようにするときちんと変更されているのですが、この振る舞いの違いは何なのでしょうか。

Comment: nihongosayonara 関数のパラメーター `df` は呼び出し元のデータフレームのコピーになります(`call by value`)。コピーを変更しても元のデータフレームには反映されません。関数の最後に `return(df)`  を追加して、`df <- nihongosayonara(df)` などとする必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えて頂いたとおりやってみたらできました。R言語の成書も読んでみてさらに納得できました。